# SSRS: Raising records up to a higher group level

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In SSRS, I want to display some exceptional records interspersed with grouped records.  Exceptional records should be displayed at a higher group level.

All records are from the same DataSet, but exceptional records can be identified with a boolean flag in the data (IsExceptional = 1)

As example, imagine a grouping hierarchy that is three levels deep.  Records are displayed at the lowest level, however users want to see some exceptional records at a higher level.  Instead of showing exception records at Group 3, users want to see all the exception records shown at the Group 2 level.  In this example, there are 10 records total, 2 of which are exceptional.

```
Group 1
    Group 2
        Exceptional Record 1      Data1      Data2       Data3
        Exceptional Record 2      Data1      Data2       Data3
        Group 3
              Non-ex. Record 1    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 2    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 3    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 4    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 5    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 6    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 7    Data1      Data2       Data3
              Non-ex. Record 8    Data1      Data2       Data3
```

Is there an SSRS mechanism for handling this type of design?

Comment: This would imply that the exceptional records are a parent grouping to the non exceptional records which really does not pair well with what you say the data actually is.  Is there a reason it is marked as parent grouping rather than either highlighting the rows in the table and sorting them to the top? That should make the data stand out as exceptional.

Comment: Valid question.  The users want to see the exception records displayed at the Group 2 level so they are all in one place.  If they were displayed at the Group 3 level, they would have to visually scan through all the third level groups to see them.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working by these steps:

- Create a Row Group at the level where the Exception records are desired.  It should be an adjacent group to the child group.  When creating the group, check the "show detail data" box to make it display detail data at that level.
- Add a Filter on the new group to show only exceptional records.
- On the lower groups, add a filter to show only non-exceptional records.